# How do I fix "Error -5" when transferring a random number of bytes using LIB-USB?

Tags: assembly, usb

I'm having an issue with a USB project using `LIB-USB`. The USB device is based on a PIC18F4550 and has a single control endpoint. The PC front-end is written in MSVC and uses Lib-Usb 1.12.

On the PC end, the program begins by setting the configuration, claiming the interface, then sending (and receiving) control messages (vendor specific), all successfully.  After what seems like a random # of bytes have been transferred (anywhere between 100 and 2000) the transfer halts with an **error rc=-5** returned from the usb_control_msg call.

On the PC-end, the calls look like this:

```
ret = usb_set_configuration(udev, 1);  
ret = usb_claim_interface(udev, 0);    
ret = usb_control_msg(udev, USB_TYPE_VENDOR|USB_RECIP_DEVICE, CMD_RESET, 0, 0, buffer, 0, 100);  
ret = usb_control_msg(udev, 0xC0, GET_FIFO_DATA, 0, 0, buffer, 8, 100);
```

The last call, which actually acquires data from the USB device, runs many times in succession but always dies after a random number of bytes (100 to 2000 in total) are transferred in this way. Changing the pipe to EP1 does the same thing with the same error eventually appearing.

On the USB device (PIC) end the descriptor is very simple, having only the EP0 pipe, and looks like this:

```
Device
db 0x12, DEVICE ; bLength, bDescriptorType  
db 0x10, 0x01   ; bcdUSB (low byte), bcdUSB (high byte)  
db 0x00, 0x00   ; bDeviceClass, bDeviceSubClass  
db 0x00, MAX_PACKET_SIZE    ; bDeviceProtocol, bMaxPacketSize  
db 0xD8, 0x04   ; idVendor (low byte), idVendor (high byte)    
db 0x01, 0x00   ; idProduct (low byte), idProduct (high byte)  
db 0x00, 0x00   ; bcdDevice (low byte), bcdDevice (high byte)  
db 0x01, 0x02   ; iManufacturer, iProduct  
db 0x00, NUM_CONFIGURATIONS ; iSerialNumber (none), bNumConfigurations  
Configuration1  
db 0x09, CONFIGURATION  ; bLength, bDescriptorType  
db 0x12, 0x00   ; wTotalLength (low byte), wTotalLength (high byte)    
db NUM_INTERFACES, 0x01 ; bNumInterfaces, bConfigurationValue    
db 0x00, 0xA0   ; iConfiguration (none), bmAttributes    
db 0x32, 0x09   ; bMaxPower (100 mA), bLength (Interface1 descriptor starts here)  
db INTERFACE, 0x00      ; bDescriptorType, bInterfaceNumber  
db 0x00, 0x00   ; bAlternateSetting, bNumEndpoints (excluding EP0)  
db 0xFF, 0x00   ; bInterfaceClass (vendor specific class code), bInterfaceSubClass  
db 0xFF, 0x00   ; bInterfaceProtocol (vendor specific protocol used), iInterface (none)
```

The actual framework is that of Bradley Minch's in assembly language.

If anyone has encountered this type of problem before I'd love to hear about it as I've tried just about everything to solve it including using a different pipe (EP1, with the same results), checking the UOWN bit on the PIC before writing to the pipe, handshaking with the PC host (where the PC must send a vendor-specific command first before the datsa is written) but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

**It Now Works!!**

Of course, I now feel "smart like a bag of hammers"  Had I read section 18 thoroughly I would have noticed the line about adding a 220nF capacitor between Vusb and ground.  Added a 470nF cap between pin18 and ground and that was all it took .... reliable transfers now.

Just another case of `"I forgot to read the fine print"`

Answer (score 1):

It's very advisable to have USB bus analyzer [Lecroy](http://www.lecroy.com/tm/products/ProtocolAnalyzers/usb.asp?menuid=67) and [Ellisys](http://www.ellisys.com/products/usbcompare.php) are high end and a little bit expensive. [Total Phase](http://www.totalphase.com/products/overview/usb/?gclid=CKOLje-aypYCFQOx1AodqkvEzA) is an example of low end one.
Using bus analyzers will help you great deal writing both your firmware and pc side software if you can afford one. Using the analyzer you can determine if the problem in your pc side (data you read is on the bus, but you can't see it in you software) or problem in your firmware implementation (you don't see data on the bus).

From your description is hard to understand what is the problem and i don't know what is error -5 mean, if you can post the define name for this i might be more helpful.
In general it's a good practice to transfer data from/to device in multiplies of max packet size. I also suggest you to read carefully relevant sections 5.5.3 (for control transfers) and  5.8.3 for bulk transfers in [USB Spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/)

**Additional comment based on the second log provided**:

The real error returned by the usb stack is in your log and its:
`vendor_class_request(): request failed: status: 0xc0000001, urb-status: 0xc000000c`

URB (usb request block) status defined in Windows Driver kit usb.h as :
`usb.h:#define USBD_STATUS_BUFFER_OVERRUN           ((USBD_STATUS)0xC000000CL)`

I found a good explanation about this error [here](http://www.jungo.com/support/tech_docs/td55.html).

Please ignore the fact that this is WinDriver defined error it's just redefined error from Windows and the explanation about what it's usually mean is correct.

[Here](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=124579) is an example why it's can happened, but there is more potential reasons for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an analyzer ("yet", at least) but I did install DebugView to see what the driver is doing, with the following output trace.  The first transfer shown (a vendor-specific one) is successful while the second one dies.  A return code of "-5" which means "I/O error" (not particularly useful) is returned from the call.

> 00002674   315.26220703    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): type: vendor
>   00002675    315.26223755    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): recipient: device
>   00002676    315.26223755    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): request: 0x04
>   00002677    315.26223755    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): value: 0x0000
>   00002678    315.26223755    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): index: 0x0000
>   00002679    315.26223755    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): size: 8 
>   00002680    315.26226807    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): direction: in
>   00002681    315.26226807    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): timeout: 100
>   00002682    315.26617432    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): 8 bytes transmitted 
>   00002683    315.26721191
>   00002684    315.26721191
>   00002685    315.26721191    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): type: vendor
>   00002686    315.26721191    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): recipient: device
>   00002687    315.26724243    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): request: 0x04
>   00002688    315.26724243    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): value: 0x0000
>   00002689    315.26724243    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): index: 0x0000
>   00002690    315.26724243    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): size: 8 
>   00002691    315.26724243    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): direction: in
>   00002692    315.26727295    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): timeout: 100
>   00002693    315.27017212    LIBUSB-DRIVER - vendor_class_request(): request failed: status: 0xc0000001, urb-status: 0xc000000c
>   00002694    315.27407837    [3684] LIBUSB_DLL: error: usb_control_msg: sending control message failed, win error: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
>   00002695    315.27407837    [3684]
>   00002696    315.27511597
>   00002697    315.27514648    LIBUSB-DRIVER - release_interface(): interface 0